# Transformar query MySQL em Eloquent (Laravel)

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho um query simples em `MySQL`, a query lista todos os dados de uma tabela fazendo um `Group By` no campo `grupo_id` e listando o ultimo dado do `Group By` baseado no `created_at`. Resumindo, ele lista o ultimo dado do grupo.

A query é simples, preciso transformar ela em uma query do `Eloquent`, segue o código:

```
select *
from fundoloja_desocupacao
WHERE created_at IN (
    SELECT MAX(created_at)
    FROM fundoloja_desocupacao
    GROUP BY grupo_id
)
```

Comment: Você tem a classe ou está usando DB? Qual versão é do Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Basicamente:***

```
$subSelect = ' created_at IN ';
$subSelect .= ' (SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM fundoloja_desocupacao GROUP BY grupo_id) ');
$result = DB::table('fundoloja_desocupacao')
    ->whereRaw($subSelect)
    ->get();
```

<sup>***Referencia:*** [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries)</sup>